# Descriptions on Fields in Big Query Views

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I know this question has been raised before and appeared to have been resolved..
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905194

But can this be done using Python yet ?

I have a script which works when I want to update field descriptions on a Big Query table but when I run the exact same script on a view nothing happens ?

The script runs and I don't get any error but it is just not updating the view in Big Query

I am using Python 2.7.13

Here is my code ..

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import datetime
import json
import sys

project='xxxx'
ds='xxxxx'
table_n='xxxxx'

startTime=datetime.now()
#Authorisation 
filename='xxxxxx.json'
client =  bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(filename)

dataset_id = ds
table_id = table_n

table_schema= []
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('BWMI_ID', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('VP_VIN_PREFIX', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CHASSIS_NUMBER', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CAESAR_KEY', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('ID', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('VEH_ID', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('LOEV_ID', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('D42_LAST_UPDATED', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('D42_END_DATE', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('USER_1_ID', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('DESCRIPTION', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('DATE_ADDED', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('DATE_ENDED', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))                            
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('SOURCE', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CANCELLED', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CANCELLED_DATE', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CRC32', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CREATED_DATE', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE')) 

original_schema=table_schema
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=original_schema)

new_schema= []
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('BWMI_ID', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('VP_VIN_PREFIX', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CHASSIS_NUMBER', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CAESAR_KEY', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('ID', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('VEH_ID', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('LOEV_ID', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('D42_LAST_UPDATED', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('D42_END_DATE', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('USER_1_ID', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('DESCRIPTION', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('DATE_ADDED', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('DATE_ENDED', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))                            
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('SOURCE', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CANCELLED', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CANCELLED_DATE', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE', description = 'Updated by python script'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CRC32', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'))
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('CREATED_DATE', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='NULLABLE'))

table.schema = new_schema
table = client.update_table(table, ['schema'])
```

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to replicate your scenario, however, the Python client libraries are working well for me

```
 #NEW VIEW
 view_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(view_name)
 client.delete_table(view_ref)
 view = bigquery.Table(view_ref)
 sql_template = ('SELECT DISTINCT user,team FROM `{}.{}.{}` WHERE score = 19')
 view.view_query = sql_template.format(project,dataset_id,original_table)
 view = client.create_table(view)
 print('Successfully created view at {}'.format(view.full_table_id))
 #UPDATE VIEW
 view_schema= [
     bigquery.SchemaField('user', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE',description='user name VIEW updated'),
     bigquery.SchemaField('team', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE',description='team name VIEW updated'),
 ]
 viewU = bigquery.Table(view_ref,schema=view_schema)
 viewU = client.update_table(viewU,['schema'])
 print('UPDATED VIEW SCHEMA: {}').format(viewU.schema) #VERIFY THE SCHEMA
```

As well the [bq commands](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#getting_information_about_views):
`bq show --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[VIEW]`

Have you tried clicking the `Refresh` button within the "View Details" screen in the BQ UI?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have now found the problem.
It is the new beta gui not showing descriptions ..
Beta Gui ....

[image: Beta Gui]

[image: Classic UI]

Classic_UI ...
Very frustrating, I've spent a day fiddling with my code to try and work out why it wasn't working.

I'll raise a bug with Google.
Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To update view schema **don't** use

```
view.schema = new_schema
view = client.update_table(view, ['schema'])
```

But instead

```
 view = bigquery.Table(view.reference, schema=new_schema)
 view = client.update_table(view, ['schema'])
```